# How to configure hive-site.xml for ODBC connection

Tags: hive, odbc

I have configured an ODBC connection in Windows ODBC Data Source Administrator and test successfully.
I want to connect to HIVE database (the ODBC connection) using Spark. As my understanding, the connection should be configured in hive-site.xml and put to folder /config. But how to configure hive-site.xml using ODBC connection? Can anyone provide an example for hive-site.xml?
I am using cloudera ODBC driver.

Environment： Windows, spark 2.3.3

Comment: _"the connection should be configured in hive-site.xml"_ > can you cite any reference about that??

Comment: Do you mean to use Spark as the execution engine?